# Why show different Arabic text in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Below html code show different Arabic text in Google Chrome(problem) and Mozilla Firefox browser(correct).

We want to take all characters separate with tag.

How we can fix it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf8>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    #dvSource {
      direction: rtl;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 3em;
      margin: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dvSource"><span>أَ</span><span>كَ</span><span>لَ</span><span> </span><span>ا</span><span>لْ</span><span>وَ</span><span>لَ</span><span>دُ</span><span> </span><span>ا</span><span>لْ</span><span>أَ</span><span>رُ</span><span>زَّ</span><span> </span><span>بِـ</span><span>ا</span><span>لْ</span><span>مِ</span><span>لْ</span><span>عَ</span><span>قَ</span><span>ةِ.</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the screenshot..

[image: Mozilla Firefox]

[image: Google Chrome View]

Comment: Because they are wrapped with spans. Wrap each complete word with `<span>`.

Comment: @CKG Did you Tried using `<html lang="ar">` on you HTML page.

Comment: We have checked with `<span>` but same issue..

Comment: Yes I tried with `<html lang="ar">` but same issue..

Comment: See http://jsbin.com/quzoneqezo/edit?html,output

Comment: I want make all character draggable with JavaScript by wrapped with spans.

Comment: Hi  Adam, you can show me same example with characters because i want to make all character draggable.

Comment: See here: http://output.jsbin.com/wibatijufi